# use popup window to open html document and call methods/ elements within it

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am having some issue with using popup window to call methods/ elements within the html page referenced. The popup window is called when user clicks on a ckeditor plugin.

Plugin.js (Popup)

```
popupEqnwin = window.open('main.html','test','width=1000,height=450,status=1,scrollbars=yes,resizable=1');
```

main.html

```
<input type="text" id="image" name="image" value="xxx"/>
```

How can I use popupEqnwin to reference to the element type named image?
I tried using popupEqnwin.document.getElementById("image").value but it did not work.

Appreciate any pointers or references. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a new window you can save its handler:

```
var popupWindow = window.open( 'yourFile.html' );
```

Then you can play with it as if it was a normal window:

```
popupWindow.document.body.innerHTML; // prints the contents of the popup's <body>
popupWindow.someFunction(); // calls some function from popup's global namespace
```

---

I mean... you should slightly change the code of the plugin so `CKEDITOR.editor.popup()` returns this handler or store it in somewhere in `CKEDITOR` namespace / editor instance.

---

I created a [ticket for this](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9403).